# Download response for S3 asset?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to generate a download response by:

`return response()->download('full URL to my asset on S3 via cloudfront');`

But I'm getting an error stating that the file does not exist.

I've checked the path, and it loads fine in a browser window.

How can I generate a download response for my asset on S3 via cloudfront?

Comment: have you tried Storage::disk('s3')->download('bucket/filename');

Comment: @JohnLobo no as I wanted to generate a response.

Comment: return response()->file(fieurl); is this failing too ?

Comment: @JohnLobo unfortunately that also fails - same error.

Comment: `response()->download` needs a local file to work. You might need to do a `response(file_get_contents(s3 file), 200, [ (correct content type length and disposition headers) ])` for this to work this way